# SQL Server 2008 Pivot, no Aggregation, complex data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I've seen a lot of "Pivot, No Agg" posts, but all of them seem to involve some pretty simple data to pivot, so the solutions work fairly well and easily. But how about when the data isn't as simple?

I'd like to turn this:

```
wwnID       Tenant                                             WeekOfTheMonth ReportingDate           TotalEmployeesPerBranch                 TotalOpenCount TotalClosedCount OpenCount_TitleAndEscrow ClosedCount_TitleAndEscrow OpenCount_EscrowOnly ClosedCount_EscrowOnly OpenCount_PreListingTask ClosedCount_PreListingTask OFPE                                    CFPE                                    OpenCount_TitleOnly ClosedCount_TitleOnly CurrentBusinessDay TotalBusinessDaysMTD ReportingDateId CreatedDate
----------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------- ----------------------- --------------------------------------- -------------- ---------------- ------------------------ -------------------------- -------------------- ---------------------- ------------------------ -------------------------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- ------------------- --------------------- ------------------ -------------------- --------------- -----------------------
3           King                                               1              2014-08-08 00:00:00.000 144.00                                  235            0                137                      0                          64                   0                      34                       0                          4.81                                    0.00                                    270                 0                     7                  21                   411             2014-09-05 08:53:11.313
5           King                                               2              2014-08-15 00:00:00.000 150.00                                  399            0                224                      0                          112                  0                      63                       0                          4.62                                    0.00                                    524                 0                     12                 21                   412             2014-09-05 08:53:19.573
7           King                                               3              2014-08-22 00:00:00.000 150.00                                  584            0                335                      0                          159                  0                      90                       0                          4.76                                    0.00                                    721                 0                     17                 21                   413             2014-09-05 08:53:26.980
9           King                                               4              2014-08-31 00:00:00.000 150.00                                  797            0                436                      0                          226                  0                      135                      0                          5.18                                    0.00                                    946                 0                     21                 21                   414             2014-09-05 08:53:35.593
4           Pierce                                             1              2014-08-08 00:00:00.000 21.00                                   85             0                31                       0                          39                   0                      15                       0                          12.00                                   0.00                                    54                  0                     7                  21                   411             2014-09-05 08:53:11.670
6           Pierce                                             2              2014-08-15 00:00:00.000 22.00                                   160            0                62                       0                          74                   0                      24                       0                          12.41                                   0.00                                    83                  0                     12                 21                   412             2014-09-05 08:53:20.000
8           Pierce                                             3              2014-08-22 00:00:00.000 22.00                                   222            0                82                       0                          107                  0                      33                       0                          12.41                                   0.00                                    127                 0                     17                 21                   413             2014-09-05 08:53:27.407
10          Pierce                                             4              2014-08-31 00:00:00.000 23.00                                   272            0                99                       0                          130                  0                      43                       0                          10.96                                   0.00                                    159                 0                     21                 21                   414             2014-09-05 08:53:36.063
```

into this:

```
Data Types                      Week 1      Week 2      Week 3      Week 4
------------------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
Tenant                          King        King        King        King
ReportingDate                   8/8/2014    8/15/2014   8/22/2014   8/31/2014
TotalEmployeesPerBranch         144         150         150         150
TotalOpenCount                  235         399         584         797
TotalClosedCount                0           0           0           0
OpenCount_TitleAndEscrow        137         224         335         436
ClosedCount_TitleAndEscrow      0           0           0           0
OpenCount_EscrowOnly            64          112         159         226
ClosedCount_EscrowOnly          0           0           0           0
OpenCount_PreListingTask        34          63          90          135
ClosedCount_PreListingTask      0           0           0           0
OFPE                            4.81        4.62        4.76        5.18
CFPE                            0           0           0           0
OpenCount_TitleOnly             270         524         721         946
ClosedCount_TitleOnly           0           0           0           0
CurrentBusinessDay              7           12          17          21
TotalBusinessDaysMTD            21          21          21          21
ReportingDateId                 411         412         413         414
CreatedDate                     9/5/2014    9/5/2014    9/5/2014    9/5/2014
Tenant                          Pierce      Pierce      Pierce      Pierce
ReportingDate                   8/8/2014    8/15/2014   8/22/2014   8/31/2014
TotalEmployeesPerBranch         21          22          22          23
TotalOpenCount                  85          160         222         272
TotalClosedCount                0           0           0           0
OpenCount_TitleAndEscrow        31          62          82          99
ClosedCount_TitleAndEscrow      0           0           0           0
OpenCount_EscrowOnly            39          74          107         130
ClosedCount_EscrowOnly          0           0           0           0
OpenCount_PreListingTask        15          24          33          43
ClosedCount_PreListingTask      0           0           0           0
OFPE                            12          12.41       12.41       10.96
CFPE                            0           0           0           0
OpenCount_TitleOnly             54          83          127         159
ClosedCount_TitleOnly           0           0           0           0
CurrentBusinessDay              7           12          17          21
TotalBusinessDaysMTD            21          21          21          21
ReportingDateId                 411         412         413         414
CreatedDate                     9/5/2014    9/5/2014    9/5/2014    9/5/2014
```

I've tried several methods of pivoting, and none of them seem to do the trick, but if anyone out there knows a way to do it, that'd be fantastic!

Thanks ahead of time!

---

UPDATE

---

This works beautifully! (initial variable declarations are for the where clause toward the end)

```
DECLARE @ReportDate DATETIME = '2014-08-31';

DECLARE @RepDateId INT = ( SELECT   MAX([WRD].[ReportingDateID])
                           FROM     [SMS].[dbo].[WSOBReportingDates] AS WRD
                           WHERE    ( [WRD].[ReportingDate] <= @ReportDate )
                                    AND ( [WRD].[Submitted] = 1 ) );

DECLARE @WSOBRepDate DATETIME = ( SELECT    [WRD].[ReportingDate]
                                  FROM      [SMS].[dbo].[WSOBReportingDates] AS WRD
                                  WHERE     [WRD].[ReportingDateID] = @RepDateId );

DECLARE @WSOBStartDate DATETIME = DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, @WSOBRepDate), 0);

SELECT  Datatype
      , MAX(CASE WHEN WeekOfTheMonth = 1 THEN value ELSE '0' END) Week1
      , MAX(CASE WHEN WeekOfTheMonth = 2 THEN value ELSE '0' END) Week2
      , MAX(CASE WHEN WeekOfTheMonth = 3 THEN value ELSE '0' END) Week3
      , MAX(CASE WHEN WeekOfTheMonth = 4 THEN value ELSE '0' END) Week4
FROM    ( SELECT    WeekOfTheMonth
                  , DataType
                  , Value
                  , SortOrder
                  , Sequence = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY WeekOfTheMonth ORDER BY wwnId )
          FROM      [dbo].[SSRS_WSOBWeeklyNumbers] AS SWWN
                    CROSS APPLY ( SELECT    'Tenant'
                                          , [SWWN].[Tenant]
                                          , 1
                                  UNION ALL
                                  SELECT    'ReportingDate'
                                          , CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [SWWN].[ReportingDate], 120)
                                          , 2
                                  UNION ALL
                                  SELECT    'TotalEmployeesPerBranch'
                                          , CAST([SWWN].[TotalEmployeesPerBranch] AS VARCHAR(10))
                                          , 3
                                  UNION ALL
                                  SELECT    'TotalOpenCount'
                                          , CAST([SWWN].[TotalOpenCount] AS VARCHAR(10))
                                          , 4
                                  UNION ALL
                                  SELECT    'TotalClosedCount'
                                          , CAST([SWWN].[TotalClosedCount] AS VARCHAR(10))
                                          , 5
                                  UNION ALL
                                  SELECT    'OpenCount_TitleAndEscrow'
                                          , CAST([SWWN].[OpenCount_TitleAndEscrow] AS VARCHAR(10))
                                          , 6
                                  UNION ALL
                                  SELECT    'ClosedCount_TitleAndEscrow'
                                          , CAST([SWWN].[ClosedCount_TitleAndEscrow] AS VARCHAR(10))
                                          , 7
                                  UNION ALL
                                  SELECT    'OpenCount_EscrowOnly'
                                          , CAST([SWWN].[OpenCount_EscrowOnly] AS VARCHAR(10))
                                          , 8
                                  UNION ALL
                                  SELECT    'ClosedCount_EscrowOnly'
                                          , CAST([SWWN].[ClosedCount_EscrowOnly] AS VARCHAR(10))
                                          , 9
                                  UNION ALL
                                  SELECT    'OpenCount_PreListingTask'
                                          , CAST([SWWN].[OpenCount_PreListingTask] AS VARCHAR(10))
                                          , 10
                                  UNION ALL
                                  SELECT    'ClosedCount_PreListingTask'
                                          , CAST([SWWN].[ClosedCount_PreListingTask] AS VARCHAR(10))
                                          , 11
                                  UNION ALL
                                  SELECT    'OFPE'
                                          , CAST([SWWN].[OFPE] AS VARCHAR(10))
                                          , 12
                                  UNION ALL
                                  SELECT    'CFPE'
                                          , CAST([SWWN].[CFPE] AS VARCHAR(10))
                                          , 13
                                  UNION ALL
                                  SELECT    'OpenCount_TitleOnly'
                                          , CAST([SWWN].[OpenCount_TitleOnly] AS VARCHAR(10))
                                          , 14
                                  UNION ALL
                                  SELECT    'ClosedCount_TitleOnly'
                                          , CAST([SWWN].[ClosedCount_TitleOnly] AS VARCHAR(10))
                                          , 15
                                  UNION ALL
                                  SELECT    'CurrentBusinessDay'
                                          , CAST([SWWN].[CurrentBusinessDay] AS VARCHAR(10))
                                          , 16
                                  UNION ALL
                                  SELECT    'TotalBusinessDaysForMonth'
                                          , CAST([SWWN].[TotalBusinessDaysMTD] AS VARCHAR(10))
                                          , 17
                                  UNION ALL
                                  SELECT    'ReportingDateId'
                                          , CAST([SWWN].[ReportingDateId] AS VARCHAR(10))
                                          , 18
                                  UNION ALL
                                  SELECT    'CreatedDate'
                                          , CAST([SWWN].[CreatedDate] AS VARCHAR(10))
                                          , 19 ) c ( DataType, Value, SortOrder )
          WHERE     [SWWN].[ReportingDate] BETWEEN @WSOBStartDate AND @ReportDate ) d
GROUP BY DataType
      , Sequence
      , SortOrder
ORDER BY Sequence
      , SortOrder;
```

and results in:

```
Datatype                   Week1                                              Week2                                              Week3                                              Week4
-------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------
Tenant                     King                                               King                                               King                                               King
ReportingDate              2014-08-08                                         2014-08-15                                         2014-08-22                                         2014-08-31
TotalEmployeesPerBranch    144.00                                             150.00                                             150.00                                             150.00
TotalOpenCount             235                                                399                                                584                                                797
TotalClosedCount           0                                                  0                                                  0                                                  0
OpenCount_TitleAndEscrow   137                                                224                                                335                                                436
ClosedCount_TitleAndEscrow 0                                                  0                                                  0                                                  0
OpenCount_EscrowOnly       64                                                 112                                                159                                                226
ClosedCount_EscrowOnly     0                                                  0                                                  0                                                  0
OpenCount_PreListingTask   34                                                 63                                                 90                                                 135
ClosedCount_PreListingTask 0                                                  0                                                  0                                                  0
OFPE                       4.81                                               4.62                                               4.76                                               5.18
CFPE                       0.00                                               0.00                                               0.00                                               0.00
OpenCount_TitleOnly        270                                                524                                                721                                                946
ClosedCount_TitleOnly      0                                                  0                                                  0                                                  0
CurrentBusinessDay         7                                                  12                                                 17                                                 21
TotalBusinessDaysForMonth  21                                                 21                                                 21                                                 21
ReportingDateId            411                                                412                                                413                                                414
CreatedDate                Sep  5 201                                         Sep  5 201                                         Sep  5 201                                         Sep  5 201
Tenant                     Pierce                                             Pierce                                             Pierce                                             Pierce
ReportingDate              2014-08-08                                         2014-08-15                                         2014-08-22                                         2014-08-31
TotalEmployeesPerBranch    21.00                                              22.00                                              22.00                                              23.00
TotalOpenCount             85                                                 160                                                222                                                272
TotalClosedCount           0                                                  0                                                  0                                                  0
OpenCount_TitleAndEscrow   31                                                 62                                                 82                                                 99
ClosedCount_TitleAndEscrow 0                                                  0                                                  0                                                  0
OpenCount_EscrowOnly       39                                                 74                                                 107                                                130
ClosedCount_EscrowOnly     0                                                  0                                                  0                                                  0
OpenCount_PreListingTask   15                                                 24                                                 33                                                 43
ClosedCount_PreListingTask 0                                                  0                                                  0                                                  0
OFPE                       12.00                                              12.41                                              12.41                                              10.96
CFPE                       0.00                                               0.00                                               0.00                                               0.00
OpenCount_TitleOnly        54                                                 83                                                 127                                                159
ClosedCount_TitleOnly      0                                                  0                                                  0                                                  0
CurrentBusinessDay         7                                                  12                                                 17                                                 21
TotalBusinessDaysForMonth  21                                                 21                                                 21                                                 21
ReportingDateId            411                                                412                                                413                                                414
CreatedDate                Sep  5 201                                         Sep  5 201                                         Sep  5 201                                         Sep  5 201
```

Thanks tons for the answer!

Comment: This is probably done the easiest with a cross tab. I prefer cross tabs to PIVOT anyway because they are slightly better for performance and much easier to read in my opinion. Here is an excellent article which explains the process. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/63681/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to UNPIVOT all those columns first, then convert your Weeks into new columns.  But in order to UNPIVOT the data, you'll have to convert all of the data types to be the same.

Since you are using SQL Server 2008, you can use CROSS APPLY to unpivot. The basic syntax will be:

```
select 
  WeekOfTheMonth,
  DataType,
  Value
from yourtable
cross apply
(
  select 'Tenant', Tenant union all
  select 'ReportingDate', convert(varchar(10), ReportingDate, 120) union all
  select 'TotalEmployeesPerBranch', cast(TotalEmployeesPerBranch as varchar(10)) union all
  select 'TotalOpenCount', cast(TotalOpenCount as varchar(10)) union all
  select 'TotalClosedCount', cast(TotalClosedCount as varchar(10)) union all
  select 'OpenCount_TitleAndEscrow', cast(OpenCount_TitleAndEscrow as varchar(10)) union all
  select 'ClosedCount_TitleAndEscrow', cast(ClosedCount_TitleAndEscrow as varchar(10)) union all
  select 'OpenCount_EscrowOnly', cast(OpenCount_EscrowOnly as varchar(10)) union all
  select 'ClosedCount_EscrowOnly', cast(ClosedCount_EscrowOnly as varchar(10)) union all
  select 'OpenCount_PreListingTask', cast(OpenCount_PreListingTask as varchar(10))
  --- union all more columns
) c (DataType, value);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fd0b0/8).  Then you'd apply the PIVOT to your Weeks:

```
select DataType,
  Week1 = [1], 
  Week2 = [2], 
  Week3 = [3], 
  Week4 = [4]
from
(
  select 
    WeekOfTheMonth,
    DataType,
    Value,
    so,
    seq = row_number() over(partition by WeekOfTheMonth order by wwnId)
  from yourtable
  cross apply
  (
    select 'Tenant', Tenant, 1 union all
    select 'ReportingDate', convert(varchar(10), ReportingDate, 120), 2 union all
    select 'TotalEmployeesPerBranch', cast(TotalEmployeesPerBranch as varchar(10)), 3 union all
    select 'TotalOpenCount', cast(TotalOpenCount as varchar(10)), 4 union all
    select 'TotalClosedCount', cast(TotalClosedCount as varchar(10)), 5 union all
    select 'OpenCount_TitleAndEscrow', cast(OpenCount_TitleAndEscrow as varchar(10)), 6 union all
    select 'ClosedCount_TitleAndEscrow', cast(ClosedCount_TitleAndEscrow as varchar(10)), 7 union all
    select 'OpenCount_EscrowOnly', cast(OpenCount_EscrowOnly as varchar(10)),8 union all
    select 'ClosedCount_EscrowOnly', cast(ClosedCount_EscrowOnly as varchar(10)), 9 union all
    select 'OpenCount_PreListingTask', cast(OpenCount_PreListingTask as varchar(10)), 10
  ) c (DataType, value, so)
) d
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for WeekOfTheMonth in ([1], [2], [3], [4])
)p
order by seq, so
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fd0b0/26).

Or you can use an aggregate function to create the new columns:

```
select Datatype,
  max(case when WeekOfTheMonth = 1 then value else '0' end) Week1,
  max(case when WeekOfTheMonth = 2 then value else '0' end) Week2,
  max(case when WeekOfTheMonth = 3 then value else '0' end) Week3,
  max(case when WeekOfTheMonth = 4 then value else '0' end) Week4
from
(
  select 
    WeekOfTheMonth,
    DataType,
    Value,
    so,
    seq = row_number() over(partition by WeekOfTheMonth order by wwnId)
  from yourtable
  cross apply
  (
    select 'Tenant', Tenant, 1 union all
    select 'ReportingDate', convert(varchar(10), ReportingDate, 120), 2 union all
    select 'TotalEmployeesPerBranch', cast(TotalEmployeesPerBranch as varchar(10)), 3 union all
    select 'TotalOpenCount', cast(TotalOpenCount as varchar(10)), 4 union all
    select 'TotalClosedCount', cast(TotalClosedCount as varchar(10)), 5 union all
    select 'OpenCount_TitleAndEscrow', cast(OpenCount_TitleAndEscrow as varchar(10)), 6 union all
    select 'ClosedCount_TitleAndEscrow', cast(ClosedCount_TitleAndEscrow as varchar(10)), 7 union all
    select 'OpenCount_EscrowOnly', cast(OpenCount_EscrowOnly as varchar(10)),8 union all
    select 'ClosedCount_EscrowOnly', cast(ClosedCount_EscrowOnly as varchar(10)), 9 union all
    select 'OpenCount_PreListingTask', cast(OpenCount_PreListingTask as varchar(10)), 10
  ) c (DataType, value, so)
) d
group by datatype, seq, so
order by seq, so
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fd0b0/28)

Comment: Yep, first thing I noticed is row header Data Types are columns in the original table. In a resulting pivot, anything you want to be a row header or column header must be values in your original table.  This is why you'd need to first unpivot to put them into a single DataType column.  Additionally, the values in each cell of a Pivot usually all come from the same column, hence another reason you will need to unpivot so that everything is in a single `Value` column as bluefeet has demonstrated.  Essentially the unpivot is normalizing your data into something vaguely simlar to a Data Warehouse.

Comment: Actually, "Data Types" was just me trying to put some sort of header in there of what it was you were seeing. :) That said, I'm gonna give this a whirl, and see what happens!

Comment: That works awesome! I used the CROSS APPLY, and then the PIVOT, and it was great - but one question - is there a way to allow for ordering the rows in a specific order?

Comment: Ideally, I'd like them to go: ReportingDate, TotalEmployeesPerBranch, TotalOpenCount, TotalClosedCount, OpenCount_TitleAndEscrow, ClosedCount_TitleAndEscrow, OpenCount_EscrowOnly, ClosedCount_EscrowOnly, OpenCount_PreListingTask, ClosedCount_PreListingTask, OFPE, CFPE, OpenCount_TitleOnly, ClosedCount_TitleOnly, CurrentBusinessDay, TotalBusinessDaysMTD, ReportingDateId, CreatedDate

Comment: @PKD Yes, you'd create a column in the cross apply that contains the sort order -- see this demo -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fd0b0/13

Comment: Hilarious - That's exactly what I was doing! :) Thanks!

Comment: I am slightly confused, however, in that it seems to mix all the data together. The resultant data set is a jumble of the Pierce and King data. (I think it's very close, just needs some tweaks.)

Comment: @PKD You'll have to use row_number -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fd0b0/26  See my updated answer

Comment: Sweet! Works like a charm! I'm gonna post the new code above! Thanks a ton!

Comment: @PKD No need to post the solution in the question that's what the answer is for